# where to put the code that populates a view that's used in different types of activities

Tags: android, android-layout, dry

I've got a `LinearLayout` (listed_venue_item.xml) that I'm using for the rows in a `ListView`.   I'd like to use the same `LinearLayout` as an overlay for my `MapView`.

To display listed_venue_item.xml over my MapView, I use `include` in the same layout as my MapView, and it works fine:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/mapVenueItemLayout"
    layout="@layout/listed_venue_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
/>
```

But now, to populate the views **inside** the included layout, I've got duplicate code: the first in my `VenueArrayAdapter` that extends `ArrayAdapter`, and the second in my class that extends `MapActivity`.

So I'm wondering where to put the code that populates the venue_layout.

My best guess is in my `Venue` class, which holds a single instance of a venue:

```
public class Venue {
    public int venue_id;
    public String name;
    public String image_code;
    // snipped several fields for brevity

    public String toString() {
        return "venue: " + name;
    }

    public static class VenueRowHolder {
        ImageView logo_image=null;
        TextView name=null;
        String logo_code;
        int id;

        VenueRowHolder(View base) {
            this.logo_image=(ImageView)base.findViewById(R.id.venueLogo);
            this.name=(TextView)base.findViewById(R.id.venueName);
        }
    }
}
```

Where should I put the code?  Inside `Venue`?  Inside `Venue.VenueRowHolder`?  somewhere else altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a class, which holds list of Venues and puts itself in ListView.

Answer (score 0):

I put it in my `VenueRowHolder`:

```
public class VenueRowHolder {
    public ImageView logo_image=null;
    public TextView name=null;
    public TextView address=null;
    public String logo_code;
    public int id;

    public VenueRowHolder(View base) {
        this.logo_image=(ImageView)base.findViewById(R.id.venueLogo);
        this.name=(TextView)base.findViewById(R.id.venueName);
        this.address=(TextView)base.findViewById(R.id.address);
    }

    public void loadVenue(Venue _venue) {
        loadVenue(_venue,false);
    }

    public void loadVenue(Venue _venue, boolean load_image_now) {
        String url = "";
        if(load_image_now) {
            url = _venue.logo_code + ".png";
        }
        BitmapManager.B.loadBitmap(url, logo_image, ImageWidth(), ImageHeight());

        id = _venue.venue_id;
        logo_code = _venue.logo_code;
        name.setText(_venue.name);
        address.setText(_venue.address);
    }
}
```

and then when I need to load a venue into the View, I do something like this:

```
        View _venue = findViewById(R.id.listed_venue_item);

        VenueRowHolder holder = (VenueRowHolder)_venue.getTag();

        if(holder == null) {
            holder = new VenueRowHolder(_venue);
            _venue.setTag(holder);
        }

        holder.loadVenue(_venue);
```